# Laravel Subfolder Issue with public folder

Tags: laravel

I have shared hosting, I have created lot of webiste on it,

recently I have created laravel project, on local it's working fine, I have uploaded that file into subfolder i.e http://myurl.com/laravel_project

but when I am hitting this url it's not working, its giving an error

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

and when I am hitting http://myurl.com/laravel_project/public it is working fine,

I want to work that pulic folder as a http://myurl.com/laravel_project

I have created `.htaccess` file on http://myurl.com/laravel_project and the code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it showing

> Page not found
>
> Homepage | Go Back

Comment: its laravel drowback you can deploy your laravel project on sub domain and your issue solve

Comment: i cannot make the sub domain because i dont have the access

Comment: we just wanted to show the demolinks to the client, when he final it we will deploy this to his/her domain with sperate hosting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to point laravel project to a public folder under public\_html in shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094509/how-to-point-laravel-project-to-a-public-folder-under-public-html-in-shared-host)

Answer (score 0):

Create a **.htaccess** file to your sub folder that laravel exist, and paste this code inside file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: where did you create the file?

Comment: myurl.com/laravel_project/

Comment: can  you clear the cache and routes and also restart the server?

Comment: how can i? its on live server??

Comment: If you have it on local, Please Try it on local.
Otherwise try to reopen it again in another browser

Comment: Same error on different brower (Safari and firefox) and dont have this on local, i an stuck on this

Comment: did you try this @daniyalbutt ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094509/how-to-point-laravel-project-to-a-public-folder-under-public-html-in-shared-host

Comment: no i cannot change the folder location because it's not on my hand