# Laravel after changing public directory to public_html

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have hosted my laravel application on shared server where public directory is public_html. The order invoice path should be `/var/www/html/public_html/user_invoices/invoice_order_447B11621531373227.pdf`

- Laravel version: 5.7
- Dompdf: "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0"

I am getting this error:

> ErrorException:
> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/myproject/public_html/user_invoices/invoice_order_447B11621531373227.pdf):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/www/html/crm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122

This is my mailable class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use PDF;

class UserNotificationsOrderPlaced extends Mailable
{
    public $data;
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {           

        $path = public_path('user_invoices/invoice_order_'.$this->data[0]->order_id.'.pdf');            
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', ['order'=>$this->data[0]])->save($path);        
        return $this->view('emails.orders')->with(['orders'=>$this->data])->attach($path);

            
    }
}
```

AppServiceProvider:

I have tried both solutions realpath and base_path but still getting same error:

> return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
> return base_path().'/../public_html';
>
> return realpath(base_path().'/public_html');
> return base_path().'/public_html';

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        if (class_exists('Swift_Preferences')) {
            \Swift_Preferences::getInstance()->setTempDir(storage_path().'/tmp');
        } else {
            \Log::warning('Class Swift_Preferences does not exists');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
  public function register()
  {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');    
            //return base_path().'/../public_html';
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });

Comment: You shouldn't change the public path because of your server's folder structure. Go to the public_html/index.php and update the paths of required files according to the application path. Everything else will work normally.

Comment: Move your application files from `/var/www/html/myproject` to `/var/www/html` and then also check to make sure the `config/filesystems.php` refers to the correct public path

Comment: What about changing `config('filesystems.disks.public.root');`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to point laravel project to a public folder under public\_html in shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094509/how-to-point-laravel-project-to-a-public-folder-under-public-html-in-shared-host)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I have manually deleted everything inside cache but it did not worked.
This helps me to resolve the issue.

[Laravel showing "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231248/laravel-showing-failed-to-clear-cache-make-sure-you-have-the-appropriate-permi)

Finally php artisan cache:clear works with above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a route to clear cache on server

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```